# Is there a way to upgrade BTRFS?

Tags: btrfs

Do I need to upgrade a BTRFS filesystem after upgrading Ubuntu, like I would with ZFS?

Comment: Where do you see any reference to version 3.0?

Comment: He's probably referring to btrfs being included in Linux 3.0.

Comment: [changelog on btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/articles/c/h/a/Changelog.html)  

0.19 is listed as the version that was released June 2009, after that they started using kernel versions.

Comment: The answer is no, the filesystem itself does not need to be upgraded.