# Upgrading btrfs-progs

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, btrfs

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and have setup a btrfs RAID 10 volume with 6 member drives for storing data. I've additionally set it up so that btrfs scrub runs every week using cron so that the quality of the data on the mount point is maintained. Everything is working pretty great, but I was doing some checking around on the system the other day and noticed that the last time the btrfs scrub command had run was 3 weeks ago.

```
> btrfs scrub status /media/data

scrub status for c93c78a0-dd9e-4b94-b501-5335d8bbf30c
        scrub started at Sun Nov 22 06:47:05 2015, running for 835849 seconds
        total bytes scrubbed: 814.57GiB with 18897787 errors
```

I tried running the scrub command manually:

```
> btrfs scrub start /media/data
```

And got the following error:

```
ERROR: scrub is already running.
To cancel use 'btrfs scrub cancel /media/data'.
To see the status use 'btrfs scrub status [-d] /media/data'.
```

I tried doing what it suggested, but it seems as if [I am hit with a particular bug in the btrfs-progs command](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#btrfs_scrub_will_not_start_nor_cancel). The version of btrfs-progs that is running on the system is 3.12, and the linked page says that it is fixed in 3.18.2, and the latest version is 4.3.1 according to the btrfs wiki pages. So how do I go about upgrading btrfs-progs?

I tried the naive approach of `sudo apt-get upgrade btrfs-progs` which didn't work. I upgraded the Kernel to 4.2.0_19, which I thought might be worthwhile doing anyways, but that didn't seem to upgrade the tools. I started looking at PPAs, but I couldn't figure out which one to setup and admittedly got scared off by the "experimental" flags on a bunch of the PPAs for btrfs. So I thought I'd ask in the AskUbuntu community, how can I upgrade btrfs-progs so that I can get the bug fix to my problem reliably?

For reference, I read the following two questions and they seem to be a little outdated these days:

1. [Is there a way to upgrade BTRFS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97965/is-there-a-way-to-upgrade-btrfs)
2. [How can I upgrade to a newer version of btrfs-tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118842/how-can-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-btrfs-tools)

Comment: A simple Google search for "btrfs tools" took me to `http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-build-and-install-the-latest-version-of-btrfs-tools-on-linux/`. You could have saved yourself a lot of typing.

Comment: Ahh, the infamous snarky Linux user. Despite giving not one, not two, but three links to show that I have tried to spend the time to research this problem on my own, you *still* made a point to be condescending in your comment. Thanks for the link though, it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-tools

after the oficial versions for every release you can see "Other versions of 'btrfs-tools' in untrusted archives." section.

yes, are "untrusted archives" but you can see that Stephane Grabber (LXD Developer from Canonical) have many ones for trusty, on this, my recomendation is:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+archive/ubuntu/buildd-backports

for backport for several developer packages, and you can see btrfs-tools here.

Now this is the first part, the other part is that you upgrade your kernel too, for kernel package for btrfs (btrfs from kernel <> btrfs-tools, different things):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

and install `linux-generic-lts-xenial` for newer kernel now.